# Celery 5.2.7 + SQS: messages are not processed by worker when internet connection is lost and recovered

Tags: python, celery, amazon-sqs

I have a FastAPI application that receives requests and sends them to an AWS SQS queue asynchronously using Celery (version 5.2.7). The application is built locally using Docker and a docker-compose.yml file.

The Celery tasks are normally sent to the queue. However, when the internet connection is lost and then recovered, the two worker pods stop receiving messages, even though the web pod continues to deliver them. The messages get stuck and accumulate in the "Messages Available" stage of SQS, and they are processed by the workers only when the application is restarted.

This problem is not specific to my local machine, as it has been tested on other people's machines with the same issue persisting. Furthermore, this bug also occurs in staging and production environments, although the trigger is even more mysterious: the workers stop processing messages every day between 3 and 4 AM for unknown reasons. Disconnecting the computer from the internet while the application is running locally has been the most effective way I have found so far to reproduce the error.

Does anyone know the exact cause of this problem and how to solve it? Using a cron job to restart the application periodically fixes the issue, but it is the ideal solution.

I have already tried to change some Celery configurations, like including and excluding the `without-heartbeat`, `--without-gossip` and `--without-mingle` arguments, without success. I also explicitly enabled `broker_connection_retry`, but it didn't work. Below, I will list the current celery configuration:

```py
broker_url = os.getenv("BROKER_URL", "sqs://")
result_backend: str = os.environ.get("RESULT_BACKEND")
task_default_queue: str = SQS_DEFAULT_QUEUE_NAME
broker_connection_retry: bool = True
broker_connection_retry_on_startup: bool = True
broker_transport: str = "sqs"

broker_transport_options: dict = {
       "region": "us-east-1",
       "visibility_timeout": 3600,
       "max_retries": 3,
       "polling_interval": 2,
       "wait_time_seconds": 10,
       "predefined_queues": {
           task_default_queue: {
               "url": SQS_DEFAULT_QUEUE_URL,
                "access_key_id": aws_access_key_id,
                "secret_access_key": aws_secret_access_key,
            }
        },
    }
broker_heartbeat: int = 90
task_acks_late: bool = True
task_soft_time_limit: int = 120
```

More information can be found on the [issue I created on the Celery repository](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/8350), which includes additional code snippets.